# How to fix "AttributeError(name) from None" when trying to use "Button.Left" in pynput

Tags: python, attributeerror, pynput

I am using `pynput` and am trying to get the mouse to click, for which I import from pynput:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
```

Then in line 8, I do this:

```
button = Button.Left
```

And as a result, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FILEPATH.py", line 8, in <module>
button = Button.Left
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37-32\lib\enum.py", line 346, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name) from None
    AttributeError: Left
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong, or what's missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just looking at [the docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#controlling-the-mouse), it should be `Button.left` with a lowercase `l` rather than `Button.Left` with an uppercase `l`.